# Both Solve and FindRoot fail to solve my equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve for `r` when the equation

```
n[r]:=
  (1 - (2 G M (1 - e^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + (r Log[e])/Sqrt[β])))/
    (c^2 r Log[e]^2))/r^2
```

equals zero using `Solve[n[r] == 0, r]`, yet *Mathmatica* just returns

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

```
Solve[
  -((2 (1 - (2 G M (1 - e^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + (r Log[e])/Sqrt[β])))/
    (c^2 r Log[e]^2)))/r^3) + 
    ((2 G M (1 - e^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + (r Log[e])/Sqrt[β])))/
      (c^2 r^2 Log[e]^2) - 
      (2 G M (-((e^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) Log[e])/Sqrt[β]) + 
        (e^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) Log[e] 
          (1 + (r Log[e])/Sqrt[β]))/Sqrt[β]))/(c^2 r Log[e]^2))/r^2 == 0,
  r]
```

Is there any way to solve this equation? `G`, `β`, `M`, and `c` are all constants.

Similar problems occur when I use `FindRoot` and `NSolve`.

Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To use `FindRoot[]`, you need to have an initial guess for the solution of your equation. Do you have one?

Comment: @MichaelLerner in your function definition you need to use a placeholder underscore, i.e. `n[r]` should be n[r_]

Comment: In a similar problem the solution is 3GM/c^2,

Comment: In general, the problem I am trying to solve is to find the value of r when the derivative of the function (1/
    r^2) (1 - ((2*G*M)/(c^2*r))*
     Integrate[t*Exp[(-t)], {t, 0, r/Sqrt[\[Beta]]}])  equals zero

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: What is `e`? eccentricity? It can't be the base of the natural logarithms because if it were, `Log[e]` would be 1.

Comment: This question have been superseded by [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107929/3066). I think it best that this question be deleted.