# Unable to solve equation for a variable by any method

Tags: equation-solving

I am looking to solve for the value of `r` when the derivative of the expression

```
 (1/ r^2) (1 - ((2*GM)/(c^2*r)) Integrate[t*Exp[(-t)], {t, 0, r/Sqrt[β]}])
```

equals zero.

But I have been unable to use the `Solve`, `FindRoot`, or `Reduce` to find a value for `r`. *Mathmatica* keeps returning

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

`G`, `β`, `M`, and `c` are all constants.

Please, any help would be much apreciated.

Comment: Transcendental equations of this sort generally do not have closed form solutions. As I said in your other question, you need a starting guess for `FindRoot[]`. For `Solve[]`/`Reduce[]`, unless you have specific values for your constants and a region of interest, they can't do much.

Comment: I assumed `[Beta]` was meant to be `\[Beta]` (i.e. `β`).  If I'm wrong, you can roll back the edit or fix it yourself.  FYI: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `GM` is not the same as `G*M`

Answer (score 2):

It would be better when writing this equation if the values of the constants `GM`, `c` and `β` were supplied.

I will set them all to the value one but it should work for any real coefficients.

First the integral is evaluated. This is generally a good practice so that in downstream processing the integral is not repeatedly evaluated.

```
Integrate[t*Exp[(-t)], {t, 0, r/Sqrt[β]}]

(* 1 - E^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + r/Sqrt[β]) *)
```

Next place that result into your original equation

```
eq1 = (1/r^2) (1 - ((2*GM)/(c^2*r)) 1 - 
    E^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + r/Sqrt[β]))

(* (1 - (2 GM)/(c^2 r) - 
 E^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + r/Sqrt[β]))/r^2 *)
```

and take the derivative

```
eq2 = D[expr, r];
```

yielding

```
-((2 (1 - (2 GM)/(c^2 r) - 
     E^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + r/Sqrt[β])))/r^3) + ((2 GM)/(
  c^2 r^2) - E^(-(r/Sqrt[β]))/Sqrt[β] + (
  E^(-(r/Sqrt[β])) (1 + r/Sqrt[β]))/Sqrt[β])/r^2
```

Next substitute numerical values

```
eq3 = eq2 /. {GM -> 1, c -> 1, β -> 1}

(* -((2 (1 - 2/r - E^-r (1 + r)))/r^3) + (-E^-r + 2/r^2 + 
  E^-r (1 + r))/r^2 *)
```

Finally (the most important step), apply J.M.'s suggestion of using `FindRoot` to determine the value.

```
FindRoot[eq3, {r, 4}]

(* {r -> 3.9647} *)
```

Comment: Jack, it is likely that the poster meant `GM` to stand for `G*M`, since `GM` itself is not in the list of constants mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help.

Comment: IT WORKED OUT. Thanks to all of your help I was able to input the values for the constants and acheive the results I needed. I cannot thank you all enough, this was for my seinor undergraduate thesis for physics and you all helped me to finish it on time.